# location.href is not working in react response coming from node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm using node as backend and react as frontend

there is the route in node this route is for payment and it works well

```
router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = await firstStep();
    const order = await secondStep(token);
    const paymentToken = await thirdStep(order, token);

    const redirectUrl = `https://accept.paymob.com/api/acceptance/iframes/796922?payment_token=${paymentToken}`;
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);

  } catch (error) {
    next(createError(500, error.message));
  }
});
```

and there is the react code where I'm calling this route above

```
  const handlePayment = async () => {
    dispatch(setOrderCourse(course));
    try {
      const res = await newRequest.post("payments");
      window.location.href = res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      // console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

It seems like the redirect is happening correctly on the Node.js backend, but the browser is not actually changing pages on the frontend.

and there is the clg from browser

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accept.paymob.com/api/acceptance/iframes/796922?payment_token=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' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8800/api/payments') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have CORS error in your setup, basically your frontend and backend is running on different ports and thats why you. are not able to access the api at all.
You can use [cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to access the api from the frontend.